# JavaFx media Player onEndOfMedia is not working

Tags: javafx, media-player, media

I'm currently trying to play a resource video on the mediaPlayer and when the video finishes I want to change scene. For this, I need to detect when the video finished.

I have the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
Media media = new Media(FireDarts.class.getResource("/videos/MicroPhoton_Intro.mp4").toString());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
         System.out.println("test");
    }
});
```

With this code, after the video finished, it should print "Test" on the output console, but it doesn't. Now here goes the really weird part: If I upload the same video to my webserver and call it directly from there, it works! Assuming this, I came (maybe wrong) conclusion that the way I get the video from the resource is wrong.

Comment: Looks like onEndOfMedia doesn't work with webstart: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2464841?start=0&tstart=0